# How to use all circle sizes in a punchcard?

Tags: vega-lite

[This VEGA-lite demo](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/circle_github_punchcard.html) of Table Bubble Plot uses all sizes, from small to big circles.

My script, illustrated below, is not using, there are only 2 or 3 sizes. How to enforce or **say to VEGA-lite use all circle sizes?**

[image]

```
{
          "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
          "data": { "url":"/_sql/myTable"},
          "mark": "circle",
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "instant",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "timeUnit": "day",
              "sort": ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"]
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "instant",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "timeUnit": "hours"
            },
            "size": {
              "field": "n_pmin",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "avg"
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "n_pmin",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "aggregate": "avg"
            }           
          }
}
```

PS: ideal also change "only blue" gradient to ["bluegreen"](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/), but I not see how to set color into color.

---

### NOTES

for @Jim request, a sample:

```
[{"instant":"2020-04-23T14:46:42","n_pmin":2210086}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T15:05:01","n_pmin":2214909}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T16:05:01","n_pmin":2159652}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T17:05:01","n_pmin":2290159}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T18:05:01","n_pmin":2235739}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T19:05:01","n_pmin":2505914}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T20:05:01","n_pmin":2517069}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T21:05:01","n_pmin":2492883}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T22:05:01","n_pmin":2535839}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-23T23:05:01","n_pmin":2519568}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T00:05:02","n_pmin":2367309}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T01:05:01","n_pmin":2384885}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T02:05:01","n_pmin":2340421}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T03:05:01","n_pmin":2369579}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T04:05:01","n_pmin":2285203}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T05:05:01","n_pmin":2206629}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T06:05:01","n_pmin":2149411}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T07:05:01","n_pmin":2218313}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T08:05:01","n_pmin":2231320}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T09:05:01","n_pmin":2163876}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T10:05:01","n_pmin":2100388}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T11:05:01","n_pmin":2040520}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T12:05:02","n_pmin":2157928}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T13:05:01","n_pmin":2099753}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T15:05:01","n_pmin":2334844}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T16:05:01","n_pmin":2430831}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T17:05:01","n_pmin":2403722}, 
 {"instant":"2020-04-24T18:05:02","n_pmin":2468541}, 
 {"...":"..."},
 {"instant":"2020-05-13T16:05:01","n_pmin":2717164}, 
 {"instant":"2020-05-13T17:05:01","n_pmin":2794972}, 
 {"instant":"2020-05-13T18:05:01","n_pmin":2824981}, 
 {"instant":"2020-05-13T19:05:01","n_pmin":2852586}, 
 {"instant":"2020-05-13T20:05:01","n_pmin":2868170}]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataset?

Comment: Hi @Jim, I edited inserting a sample.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll play around with this tonight and see if I can get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer to the main question,

> How to enforce or **say to VEGA-lite use all circle sizes**?

Say `"zero": false`. 
But, let's see in more detail how to do it in a more handmade way, to understand when you can set `scale.zero` to `false` as faster solution.

---

You can adjust the properties you're interested using the `scale` specification in the relevant encodings.

For the color scheme, you can set `scale.scheme` to any of the options listed in [Vega Color Schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/).

For the sizes, you can set the `scale.domain` and `scale.range` to desired values, where `domain` is the span of numbers in data space, and `range` is the area of associated legend marks in square pixels.

Alternatively, you can set `scale.zero` to `false` to automatically adjust the domain, and leave out the zero value (which is what is causing the "missing" circles in your chart).

Putting it together, it might look like this, using the sample data you provided ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoGrIjrZmNCABMABnv87Y-jYDMAFQCMY1GIBsfjaKILIA+jgIpmg2Nl52dgAc-gC+CiZmFlbo9o7Orp5eAKyodiV2XiHhkdGosT4AnHYNaRnmSJbWuXZOLu7egWWllUrVUfJ1xQ3+RTatIKbtnTkOPfn9XgDspeUjoRHjMTZNU-OLWV2rvQXeiTvDVQe1sW5Fm24t6QuZHdm2V+tCg17hVHjUJjYimUGj4zj9lv88n1PPYQXsxs8ils7P5Pm0LiskTc4miwYc6mIGjZEok3HCln9utd+rFSaMnhCiq9aXjvgzLkSWW42ftwTEsQ0iv5EvSCYi1n0xB4EiDguyxXU3P53s1Zb8BQrXEqKiKMRC3IkxDSinqEUz1sabKaOTE3GJnHFbYyAYrlcKhqD1eT3Li3rzzvrCYabMbfAH0S66tTZnY6V8I3afUbleVdmTnvZ-P5jl6DczjYM80Hno0xF4vKWo+Xldt4-mIXFaV40-jI-Lm0lnRqXt37I3+w7lcC29WIV5-BbNql0-DvYKlfEh8H4qmaeP7b761vns4ymOV-ym5OvE6A2rRduw9T91mY95-VWHyeGg1NlyX+u3i5g8s6um6lpiAB0YbpWIFfhCYhuEkbgNhecoHtmWzHghqabLEUHNl4dx3u2MQBIkRR1gRZT8N2AzYTEmxbPOkFoX29pFLRhStp+ZqMQ0lJ4dRnF0URDF1IkMYNIkqG9pmeQiUC4nJpCyTCVxHiojO8ExMkMmbHYKQALppCAyAAE4ANbWFANDmVAghwCEcCyFAbDKKYZBoKAACe3kgAAZjQcCCMo1gZlYSiYD5OBOegbDmR5sg6CEmA0AgcAAKqyHQ1iqH5SgyOZ2SGGZcipXoIQAO5wGFUWMCEAXmTQIQQGorUMPIJlKAAHv5QUhWF6ARalMVxSACVJSlUXpVlOV-DAbAMOZBimRANAAF5xaAA2hdYfFRWN1gAI4ML8dBqDQpAhEgZBkOZfCYONGUdK1UA6NtKhsMgtSGLECQAwoSEAwkRlKOZHRkHFhg7goUJ2CZpluYICX9cFe3oAdIDRbFJ1nZYF1pddSi3fdj3PXAr2Fe9jn+co31IL9-0g0DIOg9T3DjUwujkA9LkgCkgspEAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T14:46:42", "n_pmin": 2210086},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T15:05:01", "n_pmin": 2214909},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T16:05:01", "n_pmin": 2159652},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T17:05:01", "n_pmin": 2290159},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T18:05:01", "n_pmin": 2235739},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T19:05:01", "n_pmin": 2505914},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T20:05:01", "n_pmin": 2517069},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T21:05:01", "n_pmin": 2492883},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T22:05:01", "n_pmin": 2535839},
      {"instant": "2020-04-23T23:05:01", "n_pmin": 2519568},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T00:05:02", "n_pmin": 2367309},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T01:05:01", "n_pmin": 2384885},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T02:05:01", "n_pmin": 2340421},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T03:05:01", "n_pmin": 2369579},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T04:05:01", "n_pmin": 2285203},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T05:05:01", "n_pmin": 2206629},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T06:05:01", "n_pmin": 2149411},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T07:05:01", "n_pmin": 2218313},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T08:05:01", "n_pmin": 2231320},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T09:05:01", "n_pmin": 2163876},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T10:05:01", "n_pmin": 2100388},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T11:05:01", "n_pmin": 2040520},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T12:05:02", "n_pmin": 2157928},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T13:05:01", "n_pmin": 2099753},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T15:05:01", "n_pmin": 2334844},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T16:05:01", "n_pmin": 2430831},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T17:05:01", "n_pmin": 2403722},
      {"instant": "2020-04-24T18:05:02", "n_pmin": 2468541},
      {"instant": "2020-05-13T16:05:01", "n_pmin": 2717164},
      {"instant": "2020-05-13T17:05:01", "n_pmin": 2794972},
      {"instant": "2020-05-13T18:05:01", "n_pmin": 2824981},
      {"instant": "2020-05-13T19:05:01", "n_pmin": 2852586},
      {"instant": "2020-05-13T20:05:01", "n_pmin": 2868170}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "circle",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "instant",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "timeUnit": "day",
      "sort": ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"]
    },
    "x": {"field": "instant", "type": "ordinal", "timeUnit": "hours"},
    "size": {
      "field": "n_pmin",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "scale": {"domain": [2200000, 3000000], "range": [100, 500]}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "n_pmin",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "scale": {"domain": [2200000, 3000000], "scheme": "bluegreen"}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

---

### Automatic non-zero fit for dynamical data

Dynamical data (e.g. new data when refresh web page) is a typical case where we can't use constant domain ranges. In this other chart [on VEGA editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoGrIjrZmNCABMABnv87Y-jYDMAFQCMY1GIBsfjaKILIA+jgIpmg2Nl52dgAc-gC+CiZmFlbo9o7Orp5eAKyodiV2XiHhkdGosT4AnHYNaRnmSJbWuXZOLu7egWWllUrVUfJ1xQ3+RTatIKbtnTkOPfn9XgDspeUjoRHjMTZNU-OLWV2rvQXeiTvDVQe1sW5Fm24t6QuZHdm2V+tCg17hVHjUJjYimUGj4zj9lv88n1PPYQXsxs8ils7P5Pm0LiskTc4miwYc6mIGjZEok3HCln9utd+rFSaMnhCiq9aXjvgzLkSWW42ftwTEsQ0iv5EvSCYi1n0xB4EiDguyxXU3P53s1Zb8BQrXEqKiKMRC3IkxDSinqEUz1sabKaOTE3GJnHFbYyAYrlcKhqD1eT3Li3rzzvrCYabMbfAH0S66tTZnY6V8I3afUbleVdmTnvZ-P5jl6DczjYM80Hno0xF4vKWo+Xldt4-mIXFaV40-jI-Lm0lnRqXt37I3+w7lcC29WIV5-BbNql0-DvYKlfEh8H4qmaeP7b761vns4ymOV-ym5OvE6A2rRduw9T91mY95-VWHyeGg1NlyX+u3i5g8s6um6lpiAB0YbpWIFfhCYhuEkbgNhecoHtmWzHghqabLEUHNl4dx3u2MQBIkRR1gRZT8N2AzYTEmxbPOkFoX29pFLRhStp+ZqMQ0lJ4dRnF0URDF1IkMYNIkqG9pmeQiUC4nJpCyTCVxHiojO8ExMkMmbHYKQALppCAyAAE4ANbWFANDmVAghwCEcCyFAbDKKYZBoKAACe3kgAAZjQcCCMo1gZlYSiYD5OBOegbDmR5sg6CEmA0AgcAAKqyHQ1iqH5SgyOZ2SGGZcipXoIQAO5wGFUWMCEAXmTQIQQGorUMPIJlKAAHv5QUhWF6ARalMVxSACVJSlUXpVlOV-DAbAMOZBimRANAAF5xaAA2hdYfFRWN1gAI4ML8dBqDQpAhEgZBkOZfCYONGUdK1UA6NtKhsMgtSGLECQAwoSEAwkRlKOZHRkHFhg7goUJ2CZpluYICX9cFe3oAdIDRbFJ1nZYF1pddSi3fdj3PXAr2Fe9jn+co31IL9-0g0DIOg9T3DjUwujkA9LkgCkgspEAA) both `scale.zero` (of color and size) are setting to `false`, resulting in an automatic scale range adjust:

```
    "size": {
      "field": "n_pmin",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "scale": {"zero": false }
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "n_pmin",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "scale": {"scheme": "bluegreen", "zero": false}
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it is beaultiful! There are a way to do this automatic "fit to max and min"? My data is dynamic, changes every page refresh.

Comment: Sure, if you set ``"scale": {"zero": false}`` for the color and size encodings, it will fit the scale to max and min.

Comment: Ramain problem: I am using scale `"round":true` in an `"aggregate": "mean"` (where not make sense show  decimals) but caption/legend show "1.2", "1.5", etc.